# How to take elements from the same collection based on other atrributes

Tags: linq

Hi I have a collection of objects:

```
MyClasss{
int Id,
int ?OtherId
}
```

I want to take do sth like:

```
collection.Where(x.Id == y.OtherId).
```

Ho to perform it in linq?

Comment: Firstly, what have you tried? Secondly, when you say you want to get those where the Id equals the OtherId. Do you mean of the same object or where the Id of any object in the collection equals the OtherId of any other object in the collection?

Comment: I mean other objects with OtherId set on Id of other object

Comment: Any of the answers below work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for:

```
collection.Where(x => collection.Any(y => x.Id == y.OtherId));
```

Be aware that this will also pull out ones where the OtherId is equal to the Id on the same object.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that `Id` is an int, while `OtherId` is a nullable int.

You have a sequence of objects of `MyClass`, and you want to keep only those objects where "Id equals OtherId". Or to be precise:

> Keep only those objects where OtherId is not null, and OtherId == Id.

The easiest method would be:

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> myCollection = ...

IEnumerable<MyClass> result = myCollection
    .Where(myClass => myClass.OtherId.HasValue && myClass.Value == myClass.Id);
```